# Does anyone know how can I have this PayPal setup?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

[image: Desired setup]

The image above is the setup my client saw somewhere and wants to have the same. We currently have this setup.

[image: Current]

Anyone knows how can I tweak our setup to be like the one above? I'm completely unfamiliar with the desired setup, it's the first time I've seen something like it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Express Checkout.To open the "Pay with Debit/Credit Card" tab, you will need to pass `LANDINGPAGE=Billing` in your [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) API call.

Comment: You'll probably need a total of 3 additional parameters, actually:  SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing&USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard.  You'll also need to make sure you're using the latest API version, which is 122.0.